# Loading Magnet LINK using Rasterbar libtorrent in Python

Tags: python, bittorrent, magnet-uri

How would one load a Magnet link via rasterbar libtorrent python binding?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
import libtorrent as lt
import time

ses = lt.session()
params = { 'save_path': '/home/downloads/'}
link = "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:4MR6HU7SIHXAXQQFXFJTNLTYSREDR5EI&tr=http://tracker.vodo.net:6970/announce"
handle = lt.add_magnet_uri(ses, link, params)

print 'downloading metadata...'
while (not handle.has_metadata()): time.sleep(1)
print 'got metadata, starting torrent download...'
while (handle.status().state != lt.torrent_status.seeding):
    print '%d %% done' % (handle.status().progress*100)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This seems to be broken. If I use this and print `handle.status().download_rate` and `handle.status().num_peers` I can see that initially it is downloading but later on its losing peers and download rate is flattening. This also pertains [this](https://gist.github.com/samukasmk/940ca5d5abd9019e8b1af77c819e4ca9) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33694605/simple-libtorrent-python-client) variation. Is there something that has to be done so that peers don't disconnect?