# libtorrent, how download .torrent in Python

Tags: python

I need to use this library from Python, but I not found good documentation.

How can I dowload a torrent using this library, if I have a .torrent file?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556657/downloading-a-torrent-with-libtorrent-python) are and example using magnet link, but I need one with .torrent file.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just the link to the `.torrent` file instead of the `magnet:` link?

Comment: I found answer:


ses = lt.session()
ses.listen_on(6881, 6891)

info = lt.torrent_info('ubuntu.torrent')

h = ses.add_torrent({'ti': info, 'save_path': './'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ses = lt.session() 

ses.listen_on(6881, 6891) 

info = lt.torrent_info('ubuntu.torrent')

h = ses.add_torrent({'ti': info, 'save_path': './'}
```